# sed preserve wildcard value inside pattern

Tags: bash, sed, wildcard

I have some app config file `tmp.cfg`. And need to change some given values inside.
Here are the string examples:

```
app-stat!error!25871a5f-9f50-40ac-923d-c80a660fe21d!1!2
app-stat!queued!25871a5f-9f50-40ac-923d-c80a660fe21d!5!10
app-stat!error!fbbf0e80-8a21-4ebf-9a78-b1017c58a19d!1!2
app-stat!error!5670b363-6a5d-4fcd-819e-85786c5957f1!120!200
```

For all strings that contains
`!error!` then following some GUID and then values `!1!2` change to
`!error!` then preserve some GUID and then NEW values `!7!10`
I do not need to touch other string that contains `!error!` then GUID but different values in the end

**Here what I've tried:**
`sed -i "s/error\!.*\!1\!2/error\!.*\!4\!8/g" tmp.cfg`
It finds all string that I need but replaces a GUID actually with symbols `.*` instead of GUID number itself.
How to build sed expression in that way to preserve the wildcard part?

**The expected result is:**
`app-stat!error!fbbf0e80-8a21-4ebf-9a78-b1017c58a19d!4!8`
**The actual result is:**
`app-stat!error!.*!4!8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `sed` command should work:

```
sed -r 's/(.*)!error!(.*)!1!2$/\1!error!\2!4!8/g' file_name
```

Comment: Thanks to all!  
Just found by myself, that we can omit using two registers, and simplify to use by one like this:  
```sed -r 's/error!(.*)!1!2$/error!\1!4!8/g' file_name```  
add the flag -i to make in place replacements, it's better to use with a backup suffix like this -i.bak

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\(!error!.*\)!1!2/\1!4!8/g' file
```

Guess you need something like this.
Pattern enclosed within

```
\( ... \)
```

are saved in registers for later use and can be accessed as `\1`, `\2` … upto `\9`.

In the above `sed` expression, pattern from `!error!<GUID>` is captured in `\1` and used while replacing as `\1!4!8`.

You can omit `g` from the sed expression if you are sure that the same pattern won't occur twice on a line.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do with `awk`

```
awk '$2=="error" && $4==1 && $5==2 {$4=7;$5=10}1' FS="!" OFS="!" file
app-stat!error!25871a5f-9f50-40ac-923d-c80a660fe21d!7!10
app-stat!queued!25871a5f-9f50-40ac-923d-c80a660fe21d!5!10
app-stat!error!fbbf0e80-8a21-4ebf-9a78-b1017c58a19d!7!10
app-stat!error!5670b363-6a5d-4fcd-819e-85786c5957f1!120!200
```

- Separate fields by `!`
- Then if field `2`=`error`, filed `4`=`1` and field `5`=`1`
- Set field `4` and `5` to `7` and `10`
- `1` do print the lines